# Creating an executable with Scala/Maven

Tags: java, scala, maven

I want to be able to create a command line utility written in Scala using Maven.  Ideally, I want to be able to write a main method and have some Maven goal that will install an executable with a certain name into a bin/ directory so it can just be used as a command.

My only experience with this is with Python's 'entry_points' in setup.py which will create an executable shell script that's configured to call a particular function.

Does Maven offer something like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`appassembler-maven-plugin`](http://mojo.codehaus.org/appassembler/appassembler-maven-plugin/assemble-mojo.html) to automatically create a bin script for you.

Alternatively, write your own script and use the assembly plugin to specify how to assemble your program.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure maven has anything like that, but can create a jar with all the dependancys, and a bash script something like

```
java -cp /path/to/myjar-with-deps.jar com.myjar.Main $@
```